# Java StringIndexOutOfBoundsException encountered when reading substring

Tags: java, stringindexoutofbounds

So I have this java class which reads a file with multiple lines and whenever it reaches this part

```
      F    C    Y
```

It's supposed to read the values of that (return F, C, Y)

I've tried  ClassString = temp.substring(0, 20).trim();

but it always returns StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (eString index out of range: 20)

Not sure why, I counted that line from the start and Y is in index 20.

Comment: sir the total length or temp is 17

Comment: `temp.substring(0, 17).trim()` will work in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, of course some error checking might be needed.

```
temp = temp.trim();
String[] result = new String[] {String.valueOf(temp.charAt(0)),
                                temp.substring(1, temp.length()-2).trim(), 
                                String.valueOf(temp.charAt(temp.length()-1))};
```

or as a char array

```
temp = temp.trim();
char[] result2 = new char[] {temp.charAt(0),
                             temp.substring(1, temp.length()-2).trim().charAt(0), 
                             temp.charAt(temp.length()-1)};
```